# Lasso choose more variables than Step-wise selection?

Tags: r, cross-validation, feature-selection, lasso, glmnet

I am trying to do variable selection using R glmnet Lasso.

The data set is n=400,000 x 129 variables.

Lasso selection choose 129 (all) variables even though Step-wise selection chose 107 variables from 129.

Is it possible to occur? Or my data (or usage) do not meet requirement to use glmnet Lasso?
Outliers are treated to be within mean +/- 3σ.

---

```
library(glmnet)

fitLasso1 <- glmnet( x=exp_vars, y=target_var, family="gaussian", alpha=1)
plot(fitLasso1, xvar="lambda", label=TRUE)

fitLassoCV1 <- cv.glmnet( x=exp_vars, y=target_var, family="gaussian", alpha=1)
plot(fitLasso1, xvar="lambda", label=TRUE)
abline(v=log(fitLassoCV1$lambda.min), lty=2)
```

---

Comment: Sure it's possible.  Just to clarify what may be your sticking point, why do you suspect it shouldn't be possible?  Also, with 400,000 data points and 129 variables, if the variables are selected because of any apriori knowledge of actually being related to the target variable, the sample size is so large that they will almost certainly be included in the final model, so Lasso choosing all 129 variables doesn't really surprise me.

Comment: Reading the question, I felt pretty disturbed by "outliers are treated to be wiyhin mean +- 3$\sigma$" = autmatic deletion of anythind more thsn 3 SDs (before or after analysis?) away from the mean?! That seems somewhere between extremely arbitrary, unjustifiable, very questionable and thoughtless.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you! I understand your comment that 129(all) variables could be selected for big size (400,000) data. I was surprised because step-wise selected 107 variables (<129) contrary to my expectation that Lasso always select less variables than step-wise.

Comment: @ Björn I treated outliers the value of which are more than mean + 3σ to be just mean + 3σ, the value of which are less than mean - 3σ to be just mean - 3σ.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't expect Lasso to choose more or fewer variables than stepwise in general.  2. How many outliers do you have, roughly?